# Qsort() comparing the sum of struct ints

Tags: c++, struct, qsort

I have a program meant to take in a number n structs of students composed of their name and 3 tests scores, and must use qsort() to output them in descending order based on their total score. While I have been able to sort them, they are only being sorted by their first value.

Is there a way to sum each students values then use qsort? I have tried editing the values of number of elements as well as the pointers of the comparison function but nothing is working

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    char name[16];
    int chineseScore;
    int mathScore;
    int englishScore;
    int totalScore;
} student;

int compare(const void* p1, const void* p2) {
    student *a = (student *)p1;
    student *b = (student *)p2;
    return (a - b);
}

int main() {
    //gets input
    int n;
    do{
        cin >> n;
    }while (n < 1 || n > 10);
    student stud[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> stud[i].name >> stud[i].chineseScore >> stud[i].mathScore >> stud[i].englishScore;
        stud[i].totalScore = stud[i].chineseScore + stud[i].mathScore + stud[i].englishScore;
    }
    //sorts array with qsort()
    qsort(stud, n, sizeof(student), compare);
    //prints result
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << stud[i].name << ' '<< stud[i].chineseScore <<' '<< stud[i].mathScore <<' '<< stud[i].englishScore<< endl;
     }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, it seems obvious that you need to adjust your `compare()` function, so I'm not sure what you're asking for. BTW: Compile with warnings and submit your code (once you have it working) for review at codereview.stackexchange.com. There are several things off which will cause problems sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int n;
> ...
> student stud[n];
> ```

Is invalid in C++. It is using a compiler extension that enables the use of a C feature [variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) in C++. VLAs are **not** part of C++. Use `std::vector<student>` in C++.

You function:

```
int compare(const void* p1, const void* p2) {
    student *a = (student *)p1;
    student *b = (student *)p2;
    return (a - b);
}
```

is invalid - `a - b` is substracting **pointers** to students and then returning that value - that value has nothing to do with the values students actually have. Dereference the pointers and compare the values inside. Also, do not remove const-ness.

```
int compare(const void* p1, const void* p2) {
    const student *a = (const student*)p1;
    const student *b = (const student*)p2;
    return a->chineseScore - b->chineseScore;
}
```

> Is there a way to sum each students values then use qsort?

Declare a variable that will hold the sum and initialize it to zero. Then iterate over the array of students and add the value of something in the student to the sum variable you declared earlier.

Comment: They're sorting by `totalScore` in descending order. I think you want `b->totalScore - a->totalScore`